# VBA Track Changes with conditions

Tags: excel, vba

I want to track changes using VBA, my existing code cannot track the following sections - please see them here [missing data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6e8F.png). Right now my code tracks changes, but it cannot show column name, related project ID, Related Action Point Index and Related action point (only if Project status sheet changed), code that will allow monitor these is needed. Here is [Project Passport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohbtJ.png) and [Project Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQdXx.png) sheets, changes on those sheets should be tracked on LogDetails sheets.

Existing code (works just fine, but it is not complete):

---

```
Dim oldValue As String
Dim newValue As String
Dim oldAddress As String
 
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheets("LogDetails").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Sheets("LogDetails").Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
        Sheets("LogDetails").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    Else
        Sheets("LogDetails").Visible = xlSheetVisible
    End If
    Target.Offset(1, 1).Select
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)    
    Dim sSheetName As String
    sSheetName = "Data"
    If ActiveSheet.Name <> "LogDetails" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ActiveSheet.Name
        Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).Value = Target.Address(0, 0)
        Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 6).Value = oldValue
        Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 7).Value = Target.Value
        Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 8).Value = Environ("username")
        Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 9).Value = Now
        Sheets("LogDetails").Columns("A:D").AutoFit
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub    

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    oldValue = Target.Value
    oldAddress = Target.Address    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @eldarado. I edited your question to properly format the code. In the future you can paste in your code as-is, highlight what you pasted, and then click the `{}` button in the editor to preserve the formatting and whitespace. You can also put four spaces before any line to achieve the same.

Comment: What is the problem? Are you getting an error (include the error)? If you aren't getting an error please explain what your code does vs. what you want it to do. Be as detailed as possible.